# SQL Server: converting column into new rows in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following data:

```
Owner|    Full Name|    Revenue|
--------------------------------
John      Jane          1000
Nancy     Ginger        2000
Sanya     Brian         3000
```

I'm hoping to restructure so that everyone is listed under Full Name, along with their revenue like below:

```
Full Name|    Revenue|
----------------------
Jane          1000
Ginger        2000
Brian         3000
John          1000
Nancy         2000
Sanya         3000
```

I can do this easily by creating 2 separate views, and then doing a union - but there has got to be a way to do this in one view - instead of 2. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION ALL for this in 1 view

```
CREATE VIEW vwRevenues AS
SELECT [Full Name], Revenue
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Owner, Revenue
FROM YourTable;
```

Or this:

```
CREATE VIEW vwRevenues AS
SELECT v.[Full Name], t.Revenue
FROM YourTable t
OUTER APPLY (VALUES ([Full Name]), (Owner)) v([Full Name]);
```

But I'm not so certain if the `APPLY` method is actually faster than a `UNION ALL` when used in a view.

Comment: This option reads your table twice (or more if more columns are involved) check the solution by Yogesh for a more efficient way to unpivot the data.

Answer (score 3):

You want `unpivot` :

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES ([Full Name], [Revenue], 2), ([Owner], [Revenue], 1) 
     ) tt ([Full Name], [Revenue], seq)
ORDER BY seq;
```